# How do you multiply an openCV image by a 3 x 3 matrix?

Tags: opencv, rgb, matrix-multiplication

An openCV h x w RGB image is an array of shape (h, w, 3). What numpy matrix operation will multiply each [B G R] pixel value by a 3 x 3 matrix M?
The desired result S with image A and matrix M is given by

```
S = np.empty_like(A)
h, w, c = A.shape
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        BGR =  A[i, j]
        for k in range(c):
            S[i, j, k] = M[k][0] * BGR[0] +  M[k][1] * BGR[1] + M[k][2] * BGR[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10, 5, 3)
M = np.random.rand(3, 3)

S = np.einsum("ijk,ka->ija", A, M)

print(S.shape)
```

Gives `(10, 5, 3)`

Comment: or just `A.dot(M)`

Comment: Neither of these answers gives the desired result, which I have now specified in code added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

@Ananda was very close. The desired result is given by

```
S = np.einsum("ijk,ak->ija", A, M)
```